# Not getting dispatched action in props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux. I tried dispatching an action from mapDispatchToProps. but i am not getting it in the component's props. is there a way i can debug this to know where it is getting stuck. reportsTemplate is a function that i want to dispatch , but i am not getting it in props. Below is my connect method

```js
export default connect(
  state => ({
    users: reduxStateSelector(state).Users
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    getTemplate: async (offset, limit, filters = {}) => {
      dispatch(reportsTemplate({ offset, limit, ...filters }))
    }
  })
)(ReportsTemplateController)
```

Comment: When you `connect` your component with `react-redux`, you can access to dispatch in component props.

Comment: In `reportsTemplate` you should write an action that you want to dispatch it, But I do not think so

Comment: reportsTemplate is a function that i want to dispatch , but i am not getting it in props

Comment: That’s weird, your connections look good. I would maybe remove the ‘async’, but that wouldn’t prevent you from receiving the function as ‘props’. Is your component a class or function?

Comment: A good way to debug is to ‘console.log(this.props)’ in the ‘render()’ method in your class component or ‘console.log(props)’ before your ‘return’ in your stateless component.

Comment: i did console log props but it is empty. I am using functional component onl react hooks like useState , useEffects

Comment: Hopefully you are calling this.props.getTemplate from ReportsTemplateController

Comment: Uhh...... I guess, did you use wrap your ‘<App>’ with ‘<Provider store={store}>’?